# Current file path in Live Template

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

Is it possible to get the full path of the current file within a live template in IntelliJ? I've tried using `groovyScript("new File('.').absolutePath")` function, but that returns `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/.` and not the file path as I was hoping for.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need to use the absolute path to itself in a source file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/live-template-variables.html) (emphasis mine):

> You can use groovyScript macro with multiple arguments. The first argument is a script text that is executed or a path to the file that contains a script. The next arguments are bound to _1, _2, _3, ..._n variables that are available inside your script. **Also, _editor variable is available inside the script. This variable is bound to the current editor.**

The `_editor` is an instance of [`EditorImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/937df35ed4fd7b41fe25a0130d17add128cde75f/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/impl/EditorImpl.java) which holds a reference to the [`VirtualFile`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/937df35ed4fd7b41fe25a0130d17add128cde75f/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/vfs/VirtualFile.java) that represents the currently opened file.

Therefore, the following script gets the full path of currently opened file.

```
groovyScript("_editor.getVirtualFile().getPath()")
```

Or if you want to get the path relative to the project's root:

```
groovyScript("_editor.getVirtualFile().getPath().replace(_editor.getProject().getBaseDir().getPath(), \"\")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 the Live Template macros `filePath()` and `fileRelativePath()` are [available](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55066). A complicated Groovy script macro is no longer required.