# intellij macro or live template to get breadcrumb in the clipboard or directly in template

Tags: intellij-idea

intellij has the cool breadcrumb that is shows on/below the editor window.

is there a cool way to get this breadcrumb in clipboard?

for example <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> gets the file path with line number.

so is there a way to copy the breadcrumb?

basically i want to create my own live template/macro for a shortcut

```
  logger.info("xxx - " + breadcrumb)
```

i already have my live template doingth the above minus the breadcrumb part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get current file path as either absolute or relative using groovyScript macro:

> _editor variable is available inside the script. This variable is bound to the current editor. The _editor is an instance of EditorImpl
>   which holds a reference to the VirtualFile that represents the
>   currently opened file.

Therefore, the following script gets the full path of currently opened file.

```
groovyScript("_editor.getVirtualFile().getPath()")
```

Or if you want to get the path relative to the project's root:

```
groovyScript("_editor.getVirtualFile().getPath().replace(_editor.getProject().getBaseDir().getPath(), \"\")")
```

see: 
[Current file path in Live Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38488564/4560142)

Comment: thanks! can I also get the current function name where my mouse caret is at? cause that is the most important thing i want

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that one.

Comment: i found it - jsMethodName()