# WebStorm live templates: how to create an 'export default from' live template / How to get current folder name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm, live-templates

I am working on React projects, where components have the following file structure:

```
ComponentName/
├── ComponentName.jsx
├── possiblySomeOtherFiles.js/jsx
└── index.js
```

and *index.js* reexports ComponentName.jsx like so:

```
import ComponentName from './ComponentName'

export default ComponentName
```

I want to create a [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html) for this like so:

```
import $COMPONENT_NAME$ from './$COMPONENT_NAME$'

export default $COMPONENT_NAME$
```

How do I get the value of `$COMPONENT_NAME$`? I would like to get it from the name of the current directory, but can't figure out how to do that.

I tried setting the variable to `groovyScript("_editor.getVirtualFile().getPath()")` and `groovyScript("new File('.').absolutePath")` as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488564/current-file-path-in-live-template), but both return:

```
groovy

/
lang / GroovyShell
```

Is this even possible as of now?

Answer (score 6):

The following expression should do the thing:

```
groovyScript("_editor.getVirtualFile().getParent().getName()")
```

it works fine for me in Intellij IDEA, but not in Webstorm, because Groovy plugin is not bundled and can't be added to it:( 
Please follow [WEB-28139](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28139) for updates